# What day and time is this? 20201106T00:09:00 ISO 8061?

Tags: date, time

OK! I've invested at least 30 mins trying to understand exactly that this date/format it but I can't get an (amazingly) clear answer:

```
20201106T00:09:00
```

So the date is easy:

6th September 2020 - but the time? Is it 0900 AM? What about the "T00" bit?

Thanks - basic question I know but I can't find any joy online

Comment: I don't think there is any reference to September in that date string. Perhaps November?

Comment: This is November 6th, 2020 at 9AM. No idea where you're getting September from (that would be `09`, not `11`). Googling "ISO 8061" should give you thousands of helpful links for discerning this on your own.

Comment: @TylerH - I'm guessing the OP meant to say November, the same way I'm assuming you meant to say 12:09am instead of 9am. Probably best to not be so condescending next time...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, the quick glance caused the error, but the condescension is all imagined on your part. This *is* something OP can google in a few seconds on their own, and that's one of the most important skills for a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The "T" separates the date and time portions of an ISO-8601 timestamp. The time portion is 00:09:00 — nine minutes after midnight.